# calling function - variables

Tags: php, oop, variables, object, call

i have:

```
  echo  $test->getNum1();
  echo  $test->getNum2();
  echo  $test->getNum9();
```

how can i make something:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
  echo  $test->getNum . $i .();
}
```

?

Comment: The real question here is: Why do you have multiple functions that do the same thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
  $method = 'getNum' . $i;
  echo  $test->$method();
}
```

Comment: Alexs answer is correct. But the *clean* way is to create a method `getNum()` with an argument. Just sayin' ;)

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246172/calling-function-variables/6246189#6246189), you can also specify a variable name for a function by using [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call_user_func) or [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array).  These take a [*callback*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) as their first argument, so you can provide a string within this.  In this case you could do something like the following:

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
  $method = array($test, 'getNum' . $i);
  echo call_user_func($method);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one will be simplest and most robust (that is if you don't want to write 5 more lines with the reflection api):

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
  echo call_user_func(array($test, "getNum{$i}")); 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo eval('$text->getNum'.$i.'()');
}
```

Comment: (Recommending) `eval` is evil ;)

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with this use of `eval`, even if it is not the optimal solution. Please check the mindless fearmongering.